# Variables in JQuery selector aren't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I have a function that takes an x and y value, and, using a tables rows and columns, finds the given cell. JQuery:

```
function changeNum(x,y,num)
{
    var thisRow = $(".sudoku:nth-child("+y+")");
    var thisCell = $(thisRow+":nth-child("+x+")");
}
```

Something in the `thisCell` declaration is causing the javascript to stop.

Answer (score 3):

`thisRow` is a jQuery set, not a string. Use this :

```
var thisCell = $(":nth-child("+x+")", thisRow);
```

You might also directly use

```
var thisCell = $(".sudoku:nth-child("+y+") :nth-child("+x+")");
```

Note that if `sudoku` is the class of the table and not the class of the row, then you'd need a space between `.sudoku` and `:nth-child`.

Answer (score 0):

try lead with ""+

var thisCell = $(""+thisRow+":nth-child("+x+")");